# Gmail checker on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, software-recommendation, gmail

Is thee any gmail checker that works on 12.10?

I just want blue icon in app indicator when I have unrad emails, nothing more.

**UPDATE:** I just realized there are desktop notifications supported in gmail out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried Gmail Watcher? https://launchpad.net/gmailwatcher

Comment: I tried to install it with: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/gmailwatcher.dev` and `sudo apt-get update`. Anything more to do? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to run `sudo apt-get install gmailwatcher` after that, but I'm not sure.  I'll check as soon as I can.

Comment: @iSeth Yes, it works. It pops notifications. I guess that's good enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Gmail Watcher to receive email notifications.

First add the Gmail Watcher PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/gmailwatcher.dev && sudo apt-get update`

note: the above command also updates your package list, a necessary step.

Then install Gmail Watcher:

`sudo apt-get install gmailwatcher`

To add a new account, select the '+' (plus) sign.  Enter your account details, then click 'Load Gmail Folders'.  Select the folders you want to monitor and click save.

[image]